# "Try as I like to find the way, I never can get back by day. "

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature, poetry

Could you please help me understand the two following sentences:

> Try as I like to find the way,
> I never can get back by day.

As you can imagine I do understand each word separately, however the phrase "Try as I like" is new to me and I can't find what it means precisely. In addition, "get back by day" is something odd too, what could it mean?

It is from a [poem](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/47431/the-land-of-nod) by Robert Louis Stevenson.

Comment: It is telling: No matter your efforts for finding a way, you will never get back (home) by the time there is sun in the sky (daylight). _Try as I like_ can be thought as _Try as much as I can_ __or__ _Try as I might_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verse is called 'The Land of Nod', a poetic way of referring to the world of our dreams.  The speaker says that, however much he would like to go back there in the daytime, he cannot - he can only get there at night.

(The Land of Nod is actually a mythical place mentioned in the Bible (Genesis 4: 16). The phrase came to be used of 'dreamland' because of the association of ideas with 'nodding off to sleep'.)

Answer (score 0):

This is an unusual deviation from the actual phrase of ***'Try as one might'*** which is widely used for saying that someone is making a very great effort but still cannot do something. [Source](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/try-as-someone-might) or [Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/try%20as%20one%20might)

'**get back by day**' would describe the act of returning before the last light leaves the sky.

> Try as I like to find the way,
>
> I never can get back by day.

This means that, as much as I was trying to find a way to get back, there was no chance I would be getting back by sunset or till the time there is light in the sky.